# Second homology group of the universal cover of $(S^1\times S^2)\vee S^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces, cw-complexes

This question is related to my old question: [Universal cover of $(S^1\times S^2)\vee S^1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3613181/universal-cover-of-s1-times-s2-vee-s1). How can we compute the second homology group $H_2(E)$, where $E$ is the universal cover of $(S^1\times S^2)\vee S^1$? I attempted as follows: Since the base space $B=(S^1\times S^2)\vee S^1$ is a CW complex, $E$ also admits a CW complex structure, and its $1$-skeleton $E^1$ is the universal cover of $S^1\vee S^1$ (a picture is in the link), which is a simply connected graph, and thus contractible. So if we consider the long exact sequence of the pair $(E,E^1)$, it follows that $H_2(E)$ is isomorphic to $H_2(E,E^1)$, which is isomorphic to $H_2(E/E^1)$. But I think  $H_2(E/E^1)$ cannot be easily computed, and I got stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1-skeleton is a tree, so is contractible. This leaves us with something homotopy equivalent to a infinite wedge of spheres (if I am understanding the cover correctly), the second homology of such a thing is an infinite direct sum of the integers.

Comment: But doesnt $E$ have 3-cells?

Comment: Yes, but only because we have crossed the sphere with $\mathbb{R}$, but that is contractible so we can just ignore crossing with it